# OCL is it allow to write constraint on an operation and attribute

Tags: constraints, uml, operation, ocl

Imagine the following class Person

```
================
|    Person    |
|--------------|
|- name        |
|- age         |
|--------------|
|+ drinkWater()|
|+ drinkBeer() |
================
```

Using OCL, is it possible to set a constraint on the operation `drinkBeer()`? For instance allowing only Person >= 21 year old to drink beer?

Comment: That's possible for sure, but I never use OCL. It has that smell of being purely academical. I always write human readable constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
context Person::drinkBeer()
pre Adult: self.age >= 21
```

should probably do.

Comment: Thanks a lot I've made another post related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819795/ocl-write-constraint-on-an-operation-of-class-a-and-attribute-of-class-b