# OCL write constraint on an operation of class A and attribute of class B

Tags: constraints, operation, ocl

Follwing [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815870/ocl-is-it-allow-to-write-constraint-on-an-operation-and-attribute):

I would like to know if OCL allows the following.

Imagine the following UML diagram.

How to use ocl to model: "a person can drinkWater() only if he is from country name 'ABCD'" AND if the population of the country is >= 1000000"

Of course, the example is purely fictive.

```
================                  ================
|    Person    |                  |    Country   |
|--------------|                  |--------------|
|- name        |------------------|- id          |
|- age         |                  |- name        |
|--------------|                  |- population  |
|+ drinkWater()|                  ================
|+ drinkBeer() |                  
================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to name the role of `Country` (create a named attribute inside `Person`). So let's name that `country`. This of course can be used "as usual":

```
context Person::drinkWater()
pre Enough: self.country.name == "ABCD" and self.country.population >= 1000000
```

Comment: Hello Thomas. Thanks a lot for your answer. Just a question: what do you mean by "Enough" ?

Comment: `Enough` is the name of the constraint. It could be left away, but I thought this name would fit here.

Comment: It is helpful, but not necessary, to explicitly provide a Person::country Property. All associations are always navigable in OCL (in both directions for Objects). For unambiguous cases, the target type defines an implicit role, so just access the "Country" property. For ambiguous cases the ambiguity can be resolved by qualifying with the opposite which in this unrealistically totally unnamed example must be "Country[Person]"

Comment: @EdWillink Thanks for the clarification. I have to confess that my knowledge of OCL itself is only very rudimentary.